# Swift class Data and UITableViewController runtime error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a runtime error. Iv just read "App Development With Swift "

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an 
>   Optional value"

Please help, I'm already familiar with `if let` , conditional binding, not sure where I'd have to use it in this case to get my UIImage to show up .

Still overall new to swift and IOS
Identifier is already set up , and the `tableViewController` on storyboard is also set to `MammaSitaTableViewController`.

I can get the text property itself to show up on screen but only if I take off the image property.

```
class MammaSitaTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var mammaSitas : [MammaSita] =
    [
        MammaSita(name: "Megan Fox", photo: UIImage(contentsOfFile: "Megan.jpg")! ),
        MammaSita(name: "Scarlet Johanson", photo: UIImage(contentsOfFile: "Scarlet.jpg")! ),
        MammaSita(name: "Bella Hadid", photo: UIImage(contentsOfFile: "Bella.jpg")! )

    ]   // end of delcared array mammaSitas
 }          


 // MARK: - Table view data source
//numberOfSections Optional
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

//
// numberOfRowsInSection manditory to use dataSource
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        return mammaSitas.count
    } else {
        return 0
    }

}

//
// cellForRowAtIndexPath manditory to us dataSource
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //1 dequeueReusableCell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WomenCell", for: indexPath)

    //2 fetch model object to be displayed
   let mamaCita = mammaSitas[ indexPath.row ]

    //3 configure cells properties
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(mamaCita.name)"
    cell.imageView?.image = mamaCita.photo 

    //4 return cell
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting this error?

Comment: `UIImage(contentsOfFile: "Megan.jpg")!` should probably be `UIImage(named: "Megan.jpg")!`

Comment: Im getting this error in the MammaSitaTableViewController class. Inside the array iv created.   Let me also try UiImage(named: ) as sweeper suggested

Comment: sweeper that was exactly it... feel dumb. thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional binding in following way...

```
var mammaSitas = [MammaSita]()
    if let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "Megan.jpg") {
        let obj = MammaSita(name: "Megan Fox", photo: img)
        mammaSitas.append(obj)
    }

    if let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "Scarlet.jpg") {
        let obj = MammaSita(name: "Scarlet Johanson", photo:  img)
        mammaSitas.append(obj)
    }

    if let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "Bella.jpg") {
        let obj = MammaSita(name: "Bella Hadid", photo: img)
        mammaSitas.append(obj)
    }
```

If you've image in image assets then you need to use the following to get an image.

```
 let img = UIImage(named: "Megan.jpg")
```

You are using `contentsOfFile:` to get an image, so there should be probably an image path instead of image name (eg. "Megan.jpg").

```
let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: <#imagePath#>) //not the image name "Megan.jpg"
```

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

The only unwraping of optional value in your code is in mammaSitas array constructor:
UIImage(contentsOfFile: "Megan.jpg")! and others.

So check if files with images really exist on their paths.

Answer (score 0):

Check your assets you probably have a typing error on images name or a space or something like that. To prevent the error when you initialize the table of the images, after each image instead of

```
UIImage(contentsOfFile: "imageName.jpg")!
```

write this

```
UIImage(contentsOfFile: "imageName.jpg") ?? UIImage()
```

and instead of an error you will have an empty image

If this doesn't fix the issue then the problem is in the nil variable is  IBoutlet of the image view inside the cell. So place a debugger and see whitch is nil